# How Do You Determine The PID of the Parent of a Process

Tags: erlang

I have a process in erlang that is supposed to do something immediately after spawn, then send the result back to the parent when it is finished.  How do I figure out the PID of the process that spawned it?

Comment: For OTP and other processes using `proc_lib`, see [How to find the supervisor of an OTP process?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4132317/how-to-find-the-supervisor-of-an-otp-process)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should pass self() to the child as one of the arguments to the entry function.

```
spawn_link(?MODULE, child, [self()]).
```

Answer (score 4):

@Eridius' answer is the preferred way to do it. Requiring a process to register a name may have unintended side-effects such as increasing the visibility of the process not to mention the hassle of coming up with unique names when you have lots of processes.

Answer (score 4):

The best way is definitely to pass it as an argument to the function called to start the child process. If you are spawning funs, which generally is a Good Thing to do, be careful of doing:

```
spawn_link(fun () -> child(self()) end)
```

which will NOT do as you intended. (Hint: when is self() called)

Generally you should avoid registering a process, i.e. giving it a global name, unless you really want it to be globally known. Spawning a fun means that you don't have to export the spawned function as you should generally avoid exporting functions that aren't meant to be called from other modules.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the BIF register to give the spawning / parent process a name (an atom) then refer back to the registered name from other processes.

> FUNC() ->
>
> > %% Do something
> >     %% Then send message to parent
> >     parent ! MESSAGE.
>
> ...
>
> register(parent, self()),
>   spawn(MODULE, FUNC, [ARGS]).

See [Getting Started With Erlang §3.3](http://www.erlang.org/doc/getting_started/conc_prog.html#3.3) and [The Erlang Reference Manual §10.3](http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/processes.html#10.3).

Comment: While you could do it by registering a name, it is not at all a good idea. This post would be better if you actively discouraged for doing it and explained the problems.

Comment: Back in the private beta (this question dates back to about a week after the private beta began) the discussion aspect of the site was not terribly well-formed.  I didn't really want to state an opinion, merely state an alternative approach.  I think the pros and cons have been adequately addressed in the other answers / posts.