# How to find the supervisor of an OTP process?

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp, erlang-supervisor

Are there functions which would allow an OTP process to find the pid of its supervisor?

Comment: No idea, but afaik you can get the linked processes and the supervisor is one of them.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The data is hidden in the process dictionary (of any process spawned with `proc_lib`) under the entry `'$ancestors'`:

```
1> proc_lib:spawn(fun() -> timer:sleep(infinity) end).
<0.33.0>
2> i(0,33,0).
[{current_function,{timer,sleep,1}},
 {initial_call,{proc_lib,init_p,3}},
 {status,waiting},
 {message_queue_len,0},
 {messages,[]},
 {links,[]},
 {dictionary,[{'$ancestors',[<0.31.0>]},
              {'$initial_call',{erl_eval,'-expr/5-fun-1-',0}}]},
 {trap_exit,false},
 {error_handler,error_handler},
 {priority,normal},
 {group_leader,<0.24.0>},
 {total_heap_size,233},
 {heap_size,233},
 {stack_size,6},
 {reductions,62},
 {garbage_collection,[{min_bin_vheap_size,46368},
                      {min_heap_size,233},
                      {fullsweep_after,65535},
                      {minor_gcs,0}]},
 {suspending,[]}]
```

Here the line that interests us is `{dictionary,[{'$ancestors',[<0.31.0>]},`.

Note that this is the kind of stuff you should rarely have any reason to use yourself. As far as I know, it's mostly used to handle clean termination in supervision trees rather than introspection for whatever code you have. Handle with care.

A cleaner way to do things without messing with OTP's sensible innards would be to *have the supervisor pass its own pid as an argument to the process when starting it*. This should be far less confusing for the people who'll read your code.

Comment: I'd go with the pass of the supervisor pid as well. It is simpler to implement and maintain.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it wrong, here's our solution:

```
%% @spec get_ancestors(proc()) -> [proc()]
%% @doc Find the supervisor for a process by introspection of proc_lib
%% $ancestors (WARNING: relies on an implementation detail of OTP).
get_ancestors(Pid) when is_pid(Pid) ->
    case erlang:process_info(Pid, dictionary) of
        {dictionary, D} ->
            ancestors_from_dict(D);
        _ ->
            []
    end;
get_ancestors(undefined) ->
    [];
get_ancestors(Name) when is_atom(Name) ->
    get_ancestors(whereis(Name)).

ancestors_from_dict([]) ->
    [];
ancestors_from_dict([{'$ancestors', Ancestors} | _Rest]) ->
    Ancestors;
ancestors_from_dict([_Head | Rest]) ->
    ancestors_from_dict(Rest).
```