# Get PID of myself (supervisor)

Tags: erlang

I create a supervisor that creates a child (e.g., process listening on a port). I want to pass the supervisor's PID `SupPid` to the child, so it can dynamically start other children with [`supervisor:start_child()`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/supervisor.html#start_child-2) (e.g., when the connection is received). How to get the supervisor's PID, from within the supervisor?

```
-module(the_supervisor)

start_link() ->
    supervisor:start_link({local, ?MODULE}, ?MODULE, []).

init([]) ->
    SupPid = get_my_own_pid(), % <-- get pid of the supervisor and pass it later
    ChildSpec = ?CHILD_WITH_ARGS(some_children, worker, [SupPid]),
    {ok, {{one_for_one, 5, 10},
          [ChildSpec]} }.
```

**Related**

- [How to find the supervisor of an OTP process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4132317/how-to-find-the-supervisor-of-an-otp-process)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the [`erlang:self()`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#self-0) function.